# Construct new columns out of the attributes of particular columns in R (using base R, if possible)

Tags: r, dataframe

Supppose I have this data-frame:

```rb
my_df <- data.frame(area = c(200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601),
                    type = c("urban", "forest", "shrubs", "water", "vegetation", "urban", "forest", "shrubs", "water", "vegetation"),
                    year = c(2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016))
my_df
#>    area       type year
#> 1   200      urban 2015
#> 2   300     forest 2015
#> 3   400     shrubs 2015
#> 4   500      water 2015
#> 5   600 vegetation 2015
#> 6   201      urban 2016
#> 7   301     forest 2016
#> 8   401     shrubs 2016
#> 9   501      water 2016
#> 10  601 vegetation 2016
```

I would like to convert the attributes from column `type` to new column names with expected output like this:

```rb
#>   urban forest shrubs water vegetation year
#> 1   200    300    400   500        600 2015
#> 2   201    301    401   501        601 2016
```

I however encountered similar questions here and ended up using `tidyr::pivot_wider` but I couldn't get exactly what I wanted.
It would be great help if you could help me on this part. If possible, base R functions would be preferred.

Comment: Did you try `tidyr::pivot_wider(my_df, names_from = "type", values_from = "area")`? And if yes: why this wasn't exactly what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel like stupid posting this question. Thank you @MartinGal